# Implement hook_block_configure on theme

Tags: 7, theming

Is it possible to implement a hook_block_configure inside a theme? I would like to have a configuration that is related to my theme in each block but don't want to implement this in a module because I'd generate a dependency from the theme to the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, I must use a module for that, only because of [module_invoke](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) use to call the hook.

Also, I was thinking that you could just add your functions on template.php, but this file is only included in the [theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) function, that doesn't allow you add some stuff, expect throw theme override.